# Abp Castle Dependency injection abstract class

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

An abstract class inherits an interface, and then the abstract class has multiple implementations.How should I inject?

---

interface:

```
public interface IStatementsDetailService<T> : IApplicationService where T : ReportFinancialStatementsDetailItem, new()
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 获取销账明细
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestDto"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Task<ReportFinancialStatementsDetailDto<T>>
            ReportFinancialStatementsDetail(ReportFinancialStatementsDetailRequest requestDto);
    }
```

---

abstract class:

```
public abstract class StatementsDetailBaseService<T> : FanjiaFinancialSystemAppServiceBase, IStatementsDetailService<T> where T : ReportFinancialStatementsDetailItem, new(){
   public abstract Task<ReportFinancialStatementsDetailDto<T>> ReportFinancialStatementsDetail(ReportFinancialStatementsDetailRequest requestDto);
}
```

---

A:

```
public class MICEVisaStatementsDetailService : StatementsDetailBaseService<MICEVisaItem>{
 public async override Task<ReportFinancialStatementsDetailDto<MICEVisaItem>> ReportFinancialStatementsDetail(ReportFinancialStatementsDetailRequest requestDto){
 }
}
```

---

B:

```
public class FlightStatementsDetailService : StatementsDetailBaseService<FlightDetailItem>{
 public async override Task<ReportFinancialStatementsDetailDto<FlightDetailItem>> ReportFinancialStatementsDetail(ReportFinancialStatementsDetailRequest requestDto){
 }
}
```

---

This is my injection in the module：

```
IocManager.Register(
       typeof(IStatementsDetailService<>),
       typeof(StatementsDetailBaseService<>),
       DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

But it can't work

Comment: Can't work meaning?

Comment: That's a registration, not an injection.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking here. Are you asking how to register the classes `FlightStatementsDetailService` and `MICEVisaStatementsDetailService` in your example as `IStatementsDetailService<FlightDetailItem>` and `StatementsDetailBaseService<MICEVisaItem>` respectively?

Comment: @ Krzysztof Kozmic I'm sorry, I didn't say it clearly. yes.I dont know how to register them ...